# how to upload nodejs selenium file into live server?

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I've got a website in which there is one button. that button should be click automatically through selenium.
This is ready in my local system with selenium all set up. now I want to do in live server.

1. Is this possible, does selenium work in live server?
2. How to do that?

Comment: Hi can you tell me where'you been stuck ?